# Disable OnClick Event Until Another One Is Triggered First

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 6 divs (`.selector`) set to do (`onclick`):

1. Show all tables
2. Show Nº1, Hide rest
3. Show Nº2, Hide rest
4. ...
5. Show Nº5, Hide rest

They also toggle a class `"activated"` that changes the background color.

What I'm trying to do is that once I click on *"Show Nº1, Hide rest"* disable the click option (On this div) until I click in another one first like *"Show all tables"* or *"Show Nº2, Hide rest"*.

Something like the *"once function"* but that resets as soon as another div is activated. Any way to do this?

[image]

Here is my **CSS**

```css
.selector {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #702C3D;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selector.activated {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Here is my **JavaScript**

```
$('.selector').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.selector').not(this).removeClass('activated');
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
});
```

Comment: Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) please so it will much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Aren't you really just asking for `addClass` instead of `toggleClass` if you don't want the classes to change when clicking twice ?

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes, sorry, last time I had a question I copied my code to  jsfiddle.net but this time I couldn't get it to work. Next time I have a question I'll make sure to create one so its easier! :)

Comment: @adeneo That's exactly what I was trying to do, I'll give the correct answer to someone below who suggested the same thing, but thank you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `toggleClass` to `addClass` in your click function. Then, more than 1 click in your `.activated` will have no effect (as the click is disabled):

```
$('.selector').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.selector').not(this).removeClass('activated');
  $(this).addClass('activated');
});
```

Or you can check if the clicked `.selector` has `.activated` class like:

```
$('.selector').on('click', function(event) {
  if($(this).is('.activated')) return;
  $('.selector').not(this).removeClass('activated');
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was trying to do. Tried both options and 0 problems, but I'll probably go with the second one. Good to see I can keep all the old code and just make some minor tweaks to make it work, as I am still learning.

Comment: Yes, I recommend the second one because of performance reason. You are welcome and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things to do:

1. Wrap the JavaScript inside a function
2. Unbind the click event everytime you click on something

Here's how:

```js
function clickEvent(elements){
  elements.bind('click', function(event) {
    $('.selector').not(this).removeClass('activated');
    $(this).toggleClass('activated');
    $('.selector').unbind('click');
    clickEvent($('.selector').not(this));
  });
}
clickEvent($('.selector'));
```

```css
.selector {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;

   background-color: #702C3D;
   color: #FFF; //for display purposes

   margin-left: 2px;
   margin-right: 2px;

   float: left;

   cursor: pointer;
}

.selector.activated {
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">1</div><div class="selector">2</div><div class="selector">3</div><div class="selector">4</div><div class="selector">5</div><div class="selector">6</div>
```

Comment: Accepted the other answer as correct as it was easier for me to understand what he was doing (Still learning so I wanna try and know what every line of my code does without having to ask for help later). But thanks for the "Wrap the JavaScript" advice, didn't think about doing that and then invoking the function!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
if($(this).hasClass('activated'))
    return;
```

To skip it if this was allready activated.